# Creation and Using of a database during runtime in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core backend that is currently connected to a database via the connection string from appsettings.json. Through a migration, the database can also be created or extended.

Now I have a requirement that the software should connect to additional databases with the same DbContext at runtime and if they don't exist yet create them via migration. Thereby the backend should be restarted. The user should be able to choose via the frontend which database he wants to connect to or if he wants to create a new one.

At the moment I am not clear how to implement this. I hope that one of you has a good idea.

Comment: this looks like a multitenant problem, although it's just simple like configuring your DbContext via a selected option from user (not from the configuration). We know that `DbContext` should be configured at the phase of `ConfigureServices`, so we know nothing about the user as well as his first request. I think you can try putting the configuration in the `OnConfiguring` of your `DbContext` instead. Anyway the standard solution may be supporting ***multitenant*** (search more for that), otherwise as I said, it can be simpler on some aspect but more complicated on some other.

Comment: If it comes to choosing db I would use factory to return correct database from the appsetings. I would add parameter with the connection string to the context which I inject to my repository.